# Can I improve on my wrapper method?

Tags: java

While using Selenium 2, I have following statements scattered in test methods -

```
 driver.findElement(By.name(usernameBox)).sendKeys(userEmailAddress);
```

I think of abstracting them in static methods of a WebUtil class -

```
 public class WebUtils {

    public static void type(WebDeriver driver, String locator, String testData) {
         driver.findElement(By.name(locator)).sendKeys(testData);

    }
 }
```

And the method call would be -

```
  WebUtils.type(driver, usernameBox, userEmailAddress);
```

Could I improve it more, for example if I could avoid passing driver object every time, or some thing more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you extend the base class that you generally use and add your extension methods there.

here is an example to extend Selenium class.

```
public class MySelenium : WebDriverBackedSelenium
{
        public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

        public ISelenium Selenium { get; set; }


        public MySelenium(IWebDriver baseDriver, string baseUrl)
            : base(baseDriver, baseUrl)
        {
            Driver = baseDriver;
        }

        public MySelenium(IWebDriver baseDriver, Uri baseUrl)
            : base(baseDriver, baseUrl) { }

        public static void type(String locator, String testData) {
         Driver.findElement(By.name(locator)).sendKeys(testData);

    }
```

}

You initialize it as follows in a common class that is used by all your tests:

```
var driver =GetDriver(); //method to initialize driver
Selenium= new MySelenium(driver,baseUrl);    //Selenium is a protected variable accessible from your tests
```

Now you invoke type as follows:

```
 Selenium.type(userNameBox,"username");
```

P.S: Srry the above code is in c# but you can port it over to java..

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I actually prefer the [fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) of the original example.</strike>

I was wrong, [WebElement](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) doesn't have a fluent interface. `sendKeys` returns `void`. Still though, a static wrapper over the original interface seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

If the WebDriver is going to be the same every time then you could make it part of the WebUtils class like so:

```
private final static WebDriver driver = new WebDriver();
```

and then use:

```
public class WebUtils {

    public static void type(String locator, String testData) {
         driver.findElement(By.name(locator)).sendKeys(testData);
    }
 }
```

That is the only optimization I can see.

Comment: Nop I can not declare WebDriver in WebUtils class. It is part of class which initializes my browser. Moreover I would not declare it static, I used to run in to problems while using parallel test execution capabilities of TestNG As static driver runs in to concurrency issues with two different thread trying to make it point to two different browsers.